# Show a loader when In-App-Browser is getting loaded

Tags: cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

How to show loader when in-app-browser page is loading?
I try to use this method:

```
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
         ionicLoaderService.show();
})
```

But loader is placed behind the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this method . It's not 100% what i am looking for but looks fine.
it will show loading popup at first and will wait until page load completely then is going to show browser.

```
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
         ionicLoaderService.show();
});

ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
         ionicLoaderService.hide();
});

ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
         ref.show();
         if (event.url.match("result")) {
                accountCreditService.updateLocalBalance()
                ref.close();
         }
});
```